# Matlab Create an array with element of a for loop

Tags: matlab

Here's my code:

```
N = 1:999;

for i = N
    if rem(i,3) == 0 || rem(i,5) == 0
        v(i,1) = i
    end      
end
```

Te problem is that I get an Array with some zeros in, but I just want an an arraywith the values comforming to my conditions.

How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: `N=1:999;` then `v=(rem(N,3)==0)|(rem(N,5)==0);`. Is that what you want? Or are you wanting: `v= N( (rem(N,3)==0) | (rem(N,5)==0) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the OP is looking for a result like:

```
v= N( (rem(N,3)==0) | (rem(N,5)==0) );
```

though without looping... :-)

Comment: In case you're curious, your answer is 72x faster than mine. : )

Comment: !! :-).  Obviously there might be a reason the OP needs loops, but I love to look for ways to NOT use them.  You (@Fletch) are right to leave your loop there in case that is what the OP wants but it is always fun to think of ways to create a solution without loops.

Comment: Are you on the Code Review SE site? You should check it out, lots of stuff like this on there.

Comment: @Fletch... no, haven't been. Will be now. Thanks! Years ago (many, many years ago) Mathworks had contests (maybe still do) to produce the most efficient/compact code.  It was a lot of fun.

Comment: @Fletch, on that note, I learned Python years ago by doing the http://projecteuler.net/ problems. Lots of fun. (Unfortunately, Project Euler is now offline).

Comment: Thank you, that is what I'm looking for. I'm currently learning matlab by myself, and I think I see things more complicated then they really are. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using a loop for a reason, and am not removing it from my solution. However, loops should be avoided where possible.

If I understand your question, you're trying to store only those values of `i` which correspond to a true conditional evaluation. You're problem is that you're using `i` as your index value inside the assignment statement. Use the `end` index keyword. Like so:

```
N = 1:999;
v = [];

for i = N
    if rem(i,3) == 0 || rem(i,5) == 0
        v(end+1) = i
    end      
end
```